# Will mosquitoes fly through this overflow hose to breed in a rain barrel?

Tags: rain-barrel, mosquito

I've got this rain barrel setup with an overflow hose that drains into the bushes. To deter mosquitoes from breeding inside the barrel, I have a screen on the top of the barrel where water enters. I used to also have a small section of screen inside the connection between the hose and the overflow valve. However, this was prone to clogging, so I've temporarily removed it.

[image: Rain barrel with 1.5 meter hose connected to an overflow valve near the top of the barrel]

Do I need a screen at the overflow hose connection as well to deter mosquitoes? I'm not sure if mosquitoes are skilled enough to detect the water and fly all the way up this 1.5 meter hose to breed and if the young mosquitoes are skilled enough to fly down the hose to get out.

(in case it is relevant) I'm located in Rhode Island, USA.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar setup and have no issues with mosquito larvae.

If you are really concerned a few drops of an edible oil added at the top of the barrel to the water will act as a barrier to the mini snorkel the larvae use to breathe